# Cannot Connect Outlook 2013 desktop to Outlook.com

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am trying to have my Outlook 2013 Desktop connect to my Office.com but it is not working.  Here are the steps I am taking.

Account Settings -> E-Mail -> New -> Manual Setup or additional server types -> Outlook.com or Exchanges Active Sync Compatibility.

Your Name -> me
E-mail address -> the email I use to log into Office 365/Outlook.com
Mail server ->  I don't know what to use here.  Any idea?
User Name -> the email I use to log into Office 365/Outlook.com
Password -> the password I use to log into Office 365/Outlook.com

The next button does not light up until the Mail Server textbox is populated but I don't know what to use for that.  I think it is m.hotmail.com.  If I enter m.hotmail.com  or any other server and click next Outlook totally crashes.

Can anyone tell me how to configure this thing?  Thanks!

Comment: What keeps you from using Auto Account Setup?

Comment: That does not return anything.  Just hangs.  I think the hanging is due to the fact that I use my own domain name to log into my Microsoft Account and that does not resolve nicely for it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Microsoft blog you need to put:

> m.hotmail.com

as your server name. The full setup is [here](http://blogs.office.com/2012/11/15/put-the-power-of-outlook-2013-behind-your-outlook-com-email/)

[image]